# Notifications using Facebook Connect

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a web app that uses Facebook Connect in order to log in users. With this, I have their FB id and the key for login purposes. I've seen a couple of apps that send notifications to users (just like you would about a wall post) which links them to the app.

Now, I have a feeling that they are able to do that because they're in-fb apps, unlike ours which is outside.

Has anyone been able to push notifications to users just by using Facebook Connect?

Thank you!
-AF

Answer (score 0):

Facebook limits the notifications API to [apps that are on facebook itself](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/):

> Note: Only apps on Facebook.com can use the App Notifications. Also these notifications are only surfaced on desktop version of Facebook.com.

That being said, if you have an app on Facebook and a website that isn't on Facebook, you can use the credentials for the app on facebook to send notifications.  There's two things to keep in mind in that case, though:

1. The notification(s) will lead back to your Facebook app.
2. Facebook itself may not like the workaround.

Comment: can you please provide a working demo? i couldn't succeed in this also.

Comment: Remember that you can have a canvas app and a web app under the same domain.  If you want to send a notification through the canvas app, it must recognize the app domain as the same domain that is sending the notification request.  Your app domains are at developers.facebook.com -> (your app) -> edit settings -> App Domains

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/notifications/

Only canvas apps can do this. Also, with incoming layout changes to Facebook, I wonder how this will change as well.